# unable to solve a certain NullPointerException error

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I'm having a NullPointerException error when I run my program, I've read a few things on it and tried to make some changes but still getting the error.
here's the code :

```
public class Farm {
private Connection connect;
private PreparedStatement prep;
public Farm(){
    try {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
        DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE", "SHID","pikachu");

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void AddAnimal(String name, int age, double weight, String specie){

    String sql="INSERT INTO ANIMALFARM VALUES('"+name+"',"+age+", "+weight+",'"+specie+"')";
    try {
        prep= connect.prepareStatement(sql);

        prep.executeUpdate();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}}
```

My main class:

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Farm ferme= new Farm();
    ferme.AddAnimal("Cerbre", 43, 34.00, "dog");
}}
```

And I'm having this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Farm.AddAnimal(Farm.java:31)
at Test.main(Test.java:7)
```

Comment: you have not initialized Connection object `connect`

Comment: I don't see anything assigned to `connect`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must link your connect variable to your database

```
connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE", "SHID","pikachu");
```

if you don't do that connect will be null, so you get a NullPointerException

Answer (score 1):

Your `connect` is not initialized to a Connection object. you need to assign it with connection object to fix it

```
connect =  DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE", "SHID","pikachu");
```

Answer (score 0):

by looking at your code,I see that `connect` is not initialized  and this may be the main reason for NPE.

You need to initialize before making any operation on it.

You have declared connect here `private Connection connect;;` and then you are calling  `prep= connect.prepareStatement(sql);`.

As you know instance variables are by default null and so any operation on null gives nullpointerexception